# Filenames with spaces in backtick substitution

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, command-substitution

Suppose I have a file containing a space in its name such as `with space`. What should `cmd` output in the below snippet for `ls` to accept 'with space' as argument?

```
$ ls `cmd`
```

I tried `` ls `echo 'with space'` ``. The arguments passed to `ls` are `'with` and `space'`. Trying to escape the space using backslash doesn't work either. I see that using `` ls "`cmd`" `` works. But, this does not work if I want to pass multiple files as argument to `ls` with some possibly containing spaces.

The manual on command substitution also appears sparse. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

More generally, what is the output format to be followed by cmd if it wants to output a list of files which can then substituted to be used by another command using backtick substitution?

Answer (score 6):

> I see that using `` ls "`cmd`" `` works. But, this does not work if I want to pass multiple files as argument to ls with some possibly containing spaces.

That's correct. It's the same issue as with storing commands in a variable (discussed [e.g. here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)), it can't really be done nicely. The options that come to mind are:

- Have `cmd` output a NUL-separated list of filenames, then pipe to `xargs -0` to pass them to another command
- Set `IFS` to some character that doesn't appear in any filenames, and have `cmd` output the list of files separated by that
- Have `cmd` output the file names properly quoted for the shell, and then run it through `eval`.

Like so:

```
$ touch "with space" "another space"
$ printf "%s\0" "with space" "another space" | xargs -0 ls -i
1705749 another space  1705230 with space
$ set -f; IFS=%; ls -i $(echo "with space%another space")
1705749 another space  1705230 with space
$ eval ls -i "$(echo '"with space" "another space"')"
1705749 another space  1705230 with space
```

Or use `find -exec ...` if you can replace `cmd` with that.